# Updates can only be scheduled from GUI thread or from QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5, gpiozero

I'm trying to change Image with Pushbutton (GPIO PINs) stored inside a folder using QML with PyQt5 
Python Code:

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtQml import *
import os, time, sys


def btn_pressed():
    global r
    return lambda: r.setProperty("source", "/home/pi/Desktop/example/sample/img/img1.jpg")

button1 = Button(20)        
myApp = QGuiApplication([])
myEngine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
myEngine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(directory, 'simple1.qml')))
if not myEngine.rootObjects():
    print("root object not found")

r = myEngine.rootObjects()[0].findChild(QObject, "DisplayImage")
dir(r)
print("Main Thead id ",myApp.thread())
updateUI = UpdateUI()

button1.when_pressed = btn_pressed()   
myEngine.quit.connect(myApp.quit)
sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 1.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id : main
    title: qsTr("Test")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Rectangle{
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Image {
            id: img
            source: ""
            width : main.width;
            fillMode : Image.PreserveAspectFit
            objectName: "DisplayImage"
        }
    }
}
```

When I Pressed the Push Button Connected to GPIO 20 in raspberry Pi 4 , I'm Getting below error message.

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread. 
(Parent is QQmlApplicationEngine(0x10f5ba0), parent's thread is QThread(0xf6f7c0), current thread is QThread(0xa98007c8)
Updates can only be scheduled from GUI thread or from QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()
```

I also tried creating class with a method changing Image Source Property and then calling the same method(via Class Object) upon PushButton press but it shows same error message

Is there a way to set Image's `Source` Property in QML - from parent thread in Python.

In Winforms we can Avoid "Cross-Thread Violation Error" by using `Delegates`.

Can we Use `Signal and Slot` to Solve this Problem in PyQt5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gpiozero](/questions/tagged/gpiozero) uses threads to be able to monitor the gpio so as not to block the main GUI, so the associated function when_pressed will be executed in that thread but Qt prohibits updating GUI elements such as the image from another thread.

The solution is to create a QObject that emits the signal in the method associated with when_pressed since the signals are thread-safe.

On the other hand it is not good to modify the QML elements from C++/Python, it is better to export the QObject to QML and make the connections in that scope.

```
import os
import sys

from gpiozero import Button

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class ButtonManager(QObject):
    pressed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._button = Button(20)
        self._button.when_pressed = self._on_when_pressed

    def _on_when_pressed(self):
        self.pressed.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    button_manager = ButtonManager()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("button_manager", button_manager)
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(current_dir, "simple1.qml")))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        print("root object not found")
        sys.exit(-1)
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**simple1.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 1.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id : main
    title: qsTr("Test")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent
        Image {
            id: img 
            width : main.width
            fillMode : Image.PreserveAspectFit
        }
    }
    Connections{
        target: button_manager
        onPressed: img.source = "/home/pi/Desktop/example/sample/img/img1.jpg"
    }
}
```